Can we create multiple Spark executors within a single driver node on a Databricks cluster?
I have a power user compute with a single driver node and I'm trying to parallelize forecasting across multiple series by aggregating the data and doing a groupBy and then an apply on the groupBy.
The forecasting function is passed as an pandas UDF to the apply function.
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
from pyspark.sql.types import *
 
result_schema =StructType([
  StructField('ts',DateType()),
  StructField('env',StringType()),
  StructField('source',StringType()),
  StructField('granularity',StringType()),
  StructField('exog',StringType()),
  StructField('target',FloatType()),
  StructField('forecast',FloatType())
  ])
 
@pandas_udf( result_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP )
def greykite_forecast(df):
  # df -> partitioned df
 
  # Forecasting
 
  return forecast # Follows result_schema
 
agg_df = spark.read.csv('agg_data.csv',header=True,inferSchema=True)
 
env_source_history = (
  agg_df
  .repartition(sc.defaultParallelism, ['env', 'source', 'granularity','exog'])
).cache()
 
results = (
  env_source_history
    .groupBy('env', 'source', 'granularity','exog')
    .apply(greykite_forecast)
)
 
display(results)

The driver node has 16 cores, I expected that Spark would distribute the work among all the cores parallelly but soon I realized that the job was being executed serially. I looked around and found that there was only a single executor. So I tried changing that by adding spark.executor.cores 1 to the spark config file, but this didn't help.

https://kb.databricks.com/en_US/clusters/multiple-executors-single-worker
As per this doc, you need to adjust the spark.executor.memory please check.
